# Sharepoint 2010: Does free “Foundation” version is enough for document workflow tasks?

Tags: document, workflow

I wonder if Sharepoint-2010 Foundation version meets requirements of a company I work for:

- Free
- Proven extensible document workflow system for Windows
- Able to store gigabytes of document scans inside (Does Sql-Server Express appropriate for that, how does Sharepoint store images?)
- Allows to use electronic signatures
- Notification subsystem, filters (I guess Sharepoint is ok here)

Answer (score 2):

Thats a very high level list of requirements so I can only give you some pointers :-

Free only if you're using internally and already have Client CALS ([How Much does SharePoint Cost](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/11/how-much-does-sharepoint-cost/))

[SQL Server Express 2008 R2 has a 10GB limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx) - beyond that you have to look at remote blob storage or a full version of SQL Server (cost implications)

Document workflow - [built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms549489.aspx) with 3rd party tools such as [K2 Black Pearl](http://www.k2.com/en/blackpearl.aspx), [Nintex](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Pages/default.aspx) and others (no affiliation)

Notification - built in Alert Me but somewhat limited (e.g. hard to customise, can't do date based alerts etc) but there are lots of other ways you can do this ([workflow/event receivers/open source and 3rd party tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529045/dated-reminders-in-sharepoint-calendars))

Filters - static filters via web part views, filter web parts built into Enterprise version and plenty of 3rd party filter web parts available if you're using Foundation.

Comment: Just a little addition: "SQL Server Express 2008 R2 has a 10 GB limit." However, this limit is per Database. So you could easily hosts way more data if you split your content in many site collections with each having their own database.

Comment: Good point - and if you look at external blob storage then you can potentially store a HUGE site collection within that 10gb limit.